# Jquery Bubblepopup plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

im using version 2.3.1 and im getting cutted image when popups comes from bottom, works well for popup comming from top, heres an image

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/839/cutak.png/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely a CSS-problem. Possibly some margin-top on the text-node element. Check with Firebug if there are some unintended CSS.

http://getfirebug.com/